# Nothing happens after a PopUpWindow

Tags: android, button, popupwindow, onclicklistener

I sent this question before but I deleted it because I'm going to paste more code.

My problem was I'm having a PopupUpWindow when clicking and 2 buttons appear. So, those 2 buttons have OnClick, but nothing happens. I'm gonna paste my code:

```
        // PopupWindow de Exit

    Button exit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.estadisticaspopupwindowexit, null); 
    mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);


    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("no clicked");//For checking that it's ok
            mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
            // UNTIL HERE IT'S OK
            View viewexit = (LinearLayout) factory.inflate(R.layout.estadisticaspopupwindowexit, null);
            Button si=(Button) viewexit.findViewById(R.id.buttonyes);
            Button no=(Button) viewexit.findViewById(R.id.buttonno);

            // THESE ARE BUTTONS CALLED FROM ANOTHER XML FILE

            si.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){                   
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intencion=new Intent(estadisticas.this, datosusuario.class);
                    startActivity(intencion);
                }


            });
            no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v){
                    mpopup.dismiss();
                    System.out.println("no clicked"); 
// I'M WRITING THE LAST THING FOR CHECKING ON MY LOGCAST IF IT REALLY WORKS, BUT NOTHING HAPPENS

                }
            }); 


        }

    });
```

That's everything.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use

```
Button si=(Button) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.buttonyes);
Button no=(Button) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.buttonno);
```

Comment: Hey duanhong169, thank you very much. I think you could believe that I'm kind of BLIND... I didn't see it.. Thank you !! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result by using [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html). Here is a sample code to show a popup with two buttons:

```
public class UIHelper {
   public static void createInformationalAlert(Context context,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveButtononClickListener,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeButtononClickListener,
        String content, String positiveButtonCaption,
        String negativeButtonCaption) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(content)
            .setPositiveButton(positiveButtonCaption,
                    positiveButtononClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton(negativeButtonCaption, negativeButtononClickListener);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

Then, to show the popup, use the following code:

```
UIHelper.createInformationalAlert(this,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }, "Are you sure you want to exit?", "Yes", "No");
```

If you wish to inflate a custom view, use [setView(View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: Hi Lev G.

Thanks for your answer. I didn't try your answer because I saw the second one that changed just 2 words and it worked, anyways thank you :)